# Linq Condition on Group of records

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have the following data in list:-

```
╔════╤════════════╤════════╗
║ Id │ EmployeeId │ Answer ║
╠════╪════════════╪════════╣
║ 1  │ 6          │ 1      ║
╟────┼────────────┼────────╢
║ 2  │ 6          │ 4      ║
╟────┼────────────┼────────╢
║ 3  │ 7          │ 2      ║
╟────┼────────────┼────────╢
║ 4  │ 7          │ 4      ║
╚════╧════════════╧════════╝
```

Now, using Linq, I want to get those 'EmployeeId's' who have answered 1 and 4 (In Answer column).

How do I do that...??

**EDIT**

Actually I wanted EmployeeId's of those, who have answered 4 but Not 1.
In above example, EmployeeId 7

Comment: have you googled any basic linq tutorials? exactly what is the problem? is it just the query? have you set up the datacontext?

Comment: Post the code of your List and how it's populated

Comment: Please Check my Edit... Sorry for being unclear at the first place

Comment: @Gk_999: still unclear, you want all where they answered 4 but not 1. Does that mean 4 and any other answer except 1 is allowed?

Comment: Yes, 4 and Any other is allowed, but 1 is not allowed. And this condition for  a particular employeeId

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var answers = new[]{ 1, 4 };
var query = list
    .GroupBy(x => x.EmployeeId)
    .Where(g => answers.All(a => g.Any(x => x.Answer == a)))
    .Select(g => g.Key);
```

more efficient in LINQ to Objects:

```
var query = list
    .GroupBy(x => x.EmployeeId)
    .Where(g => !answers.Except(g.Select(x => x.Answer)).Any())
    .Select(g => g.Key);
```

or without the lookup collection:

```
var query = list
    .GroupBy(x => x.EmployeeId)
    .Where(g => g.Any(x => x.Answer == 1) && g.Any(x => x.Answer == 4))
    .Select(g => g.Key);
```

---

**Edit**: now you want all `EmployeeId` where there was an answer `4` but not `1`:

```
var query = list
    .GroupBy(x => x.EmployeeId)
    .Where(g => g.Any(x => x.Answer == 4) && !g.Any(x => x.Answer == 1))
    .Select(g => g.Key);
```

Comment: GroupBy was the thing I needed to know.......I had not checked your answer at the first place..... If I have checked your answer earlier, I wouldn't have gone for the edit.
Thank you very much Tim & kazim for ur replies

Answer (score 2):

Use `Where` to select only wanted answers. Then use `Select` to select employee ids.

```
var answers = new[]{1,4};

var result = list.Where(x => answers.Contains(x.Answer)).Select(x => x.EmployeeId).ToList();
```

if you want you can also use `Distinct` to remove duplicates.

```
var result = list.Where(x => answers.Contains(x.Answer)).Select(x => x.EmployeeId).Distinct().ToList();
```

If you want any answer except 1 but 4 and others too

```
var result = list.Where(x => x.Answer != 1).Select(x => x.EmployeeId).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: @Gk_999 just remove 1 from the array of answer. `var answers = new[]{4};`

Comment: The `Contains` approach is an logical `or`, not sure if that is what OP has asked for. Originally he wanted `4` **and** `1`. Now he wants `4` and any other answer except `1`.